# c++ char vector, deleting words with numbers in them plus whitespace after bad word

Tags: c++11, vector

I think I'm pretty close to solving this but I get a bus error on one of the lines.  I have a program that reads from a file that takes in all the words buy separating them into characters.  Some words have digits or punctuations in them and the program is suppose to go throw and delete those words plus any whitespace after the bad words.  Than output the new sentence.  I'm went over it a bunch of times and everything looks sound to me right now so I'm stuck. I kept counts for character(Ccount), spaces(Scount), and bad character(bcount) which are any character in the bad word and whitespace following. Here's the code for the part I'm working on.

```
if(cFlag == true){
    int Ccount = 0;
    int Scount = 0;
    int Bcount = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<chars.size(); i++){
        if(isalpha(chars[i])){
            if(Bcount == 0 ){
                ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
                Ccount++;
                Scount = 0;
            }
            else if(Bcount != 0 && Scount == 0){
                ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
                Bcount++;
            }
            else if(Bcount != 0 && Scount != 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < Bcount; i++)
                    ctemp.pop_back();
                ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
                Bcount = 0;
                Scount = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(isspace(chars[i])){
            if(Bcount == 0){
                ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
                Ccount = 0;
                Scount++;
            }
            else if(Bcount != 0){
                //for (int i=0; i<Bcount; i++)
                    //ctemp.pop_back();
                ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
                Bcount++;
                Scount++;


            }
        }
        else if(ispunct(chars[i]) || isdigit(chars[i])) {
            ctemp.push_back(chars[i]);
            Bcount = Ccount;
            Bcount++;
            Ccount = 0;
        }
    }
    chars.clear();
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<ctemp.size(); i++)
        chars.push_back(ctemp[i]);

}
```

Comment: seems like an ideal use case for the debugger

Comment: `Bcount = Ccount` looks suspicious. This seems to allow `Bcount` to exceed `ctemp.size()`, and then `for(int i = 0; i < Bcount; i++) ctemp.pop_back();` loop will exhibit undefined behavior by way of trying to pop off an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was a Ccount++ in the if else statement that doenst have any incrementers in it.  I was getting to a new word than deleting all the previous bad spaces and letters but not counting the first letter of the new word in the new Ccount.